# How to display response on the option select ? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My component vue.js is like this :

```
<script>
  export default{
    name: 'CategoryBsSelect',

    template: '\
      <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required>\
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" v-bind:disabled="option.disabled">{{ option.name }}</option>\
      </select>',

    //props: {list: {type: String, default: ''}},

    mounted() {
        this.fetchList();
    },

    data() {
      return {
        selected: '',
        options: [{id: '', name: 'Pilih Kategori'}]
      };
    },

    methods: {
        fetchList: function() {
            this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl+'/member/category/list').then(function (response) {
                //this.$set('list', response.data);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body))
                Object.keys(response.body).forEach(function (key) {
                   console.log(key)
                   console.log(response.body[key])
                   this.$set(this.options, key, response.body[key]);
                }, this);
            });
        },
    }
  };

</script>
```

The result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body))` :

> {"20":"Category 1","21":"Category 2","22":"Category 3"}

I want display the response on the value of select. But when executed, on the console exist error like this :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is the final `this.options` variable is an hash nat an array, which should be an input to `select` element, you can modify you code inside `fetchList` method like following:

```
    Object.keys(resp).forEach((key) => {
      console.log(key)
      console.log(resp[key])
      this.options.push({
        id: key,
        name: resp[key]
      })
    });
```

Have a look at working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/stvct9er/).

Comment: I want ask. Why it use setTimeout? Without setTimeout, it works

Comment: @mosestoh I used `setTimeout ` just to simulate your async call.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for helping me